# Can't TreeSet check for comparator objects at compile-time?

Tags: java, class, oop, interface

When creating an instance of the class TreeSet in Java with the default constructor (no arguments) and adding two objects of classes that don't implement the Comparator interface, the object will throw a run-time exception. Could this check be implemented at compile time?

I have tried the following code:

Dummy.java

```
public class Dummy {
}
```

TreeSetTest.java

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetTest {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        TreeSet<Dummy> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        treeSet.add(new Dummy());
        treeSet.add(new Dummy());
    }
}
```

The compiler should complain when creating the TreeSet as it doesn't implement Comparable.

Comment: `TreeSet` predates Generics, and backwards compatibility was required.

Comment: @user207421 Which would be the required changes in order to enforce that? (give n sourcecode [link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeSet.java.html) )

Answer (score 1):

If the `TreeSet()` constructor were not public, you could have checked this at compile time, with a factory method like so:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> TreeSet<E> create() {
  return new TreeSet<>();
}
```

You can only invoke this with a type parameter which is naturally comparable:

```
TreeSet<String> a = TreeSet.create(); // ok
TreeSet<Object> b = TreeSet.create(); // error
```

But the constructor is public; and there is no language mechanism in Java to allow you to restrict the type parameters used to invoke a constructor.

This constructor had to be public because it existed before generics, and so removing it would have violated backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

You could write your own function so that it needs to implement `Comparable` to compile:

```
static <E extends Comparable> boolean addWithCheck(TreeSet<E> treeSet, E e) {
    return treeSet.add(e);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
TreeSet<Dummy> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
addWithCheck(treeSet, new Dummy());
```